# JQuery Function Placing Product name and Image Alt text under featured image

Tags: jquery, css, image

I'm using this JQuery as a hover feature to display the featured thumbnail on my clients site. However, the text is showing up on the image or too far from it. I'd like it to be right below the image. Is this something I need to accomplish with CSS or a change in JW

```
function myFunction() {
    var $large = jQuery('#largeImage');

    //store the default image as the data src
    //$large.data('src', $large.attr('src'));

    var src = jQuery('#largeImage').attr('src');


    jQuery('#thumbs img').hover(function () {
        $large.attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
        var altText =jQuery(this).attr("alt");

        //alert(jQuery(this).parent().text());
        var existsClass=$large.parent().children().hasClass("prodName");
        //alert(existsClass);
        if(existsClass)
            //$large.parent().children().remove(".prodName");
            $large.parent().find("div").remove(); 

$large.parent().append('<div class="prodName" style="margin-left:220px">'+jQuery(this).parent().text()+'<br/>'+altText+'</div>');

    }, function () {
        //on mouse leave put back the original value
        $large.attr('src', $large.data('src'));
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(myFunction);
});
```

Here's the webpage URL as an example. 
http://test.pillarsoflifebook.com/ottomans/

You can see when hovering over CrissCross and Cambridge Ottomans the text is overlying the actual image. For other products the text is right below. I'd like the text to always generate below the image itself without worrying about the actual image size. Any advice?

Comment: The LargeImage2 might be changed to a div in which the image is placed in an upper div, and the text in a lower div.

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `largeImage2` and `prodName` in a div with a fixed position like below

```
<div id="tablebasesright" style="float:left;text-align:center; padding-top:29px;">
   <div style="position:fixed;top:275px;">
        <img id="largeImage2" alt="22.5 x 14 x 20" src="./Ottomans « City Living Design_files/Newland_Ottoman.jpg" width="300" />
        <div class="prodName" style="margin-left:25px;">Newland Ottoman <br />20 x 20 x 22.5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in the js part:

```
$large.parent().append('<div class="prodName" style="margin-left:25px">'+jQuery(this).parent().text()+'<br/>'+altText+'</div>');
```

Comment: This worked fine for me! I'm sure the other solutions would have worked as well and I appreciate all the input!

Answer (score 2):

on hover try to do this

jQuery('.prodName').css('margin-top', jQuery('#largeImage2').height())

Answer (score 1):

You can use figure tag to insert image with caption. Here is how your `tablebasesright` div would look like.

```
<div id="tablebasesright" style="float:left;text-align:center; padding-top:29px;">
    <figure style="position:fixed;top:275px;" width="300">
      <img id="largeImage2" alt="22.5 x 14 x 20" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Santando_Cube.jpg">
      <figcaption>Newland Storage Ottoman</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

BTW, I don't like the way your have laid out `tablebaseleft` and `tablebaseright` next to each other by adding `float: left` on both the DIVs. This way, if I decrease my window size so as not to be able to accommodate both DIVs side by side, `tablebaseright` just disappears off the screen. If you want both DIVs to always appear side by side, I would suggest using wrapper DIV around both of them with fixed width.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="tablebaseleft">
        <!-- left DIVs contents go here -->
    </div>
    <div id="tablebaseright">
        <figure style="position:fixed; top:275px;">
        ...
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then corresponding CSS would look like

```
#container{
    display: table;
}
#tablebaseleft{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 480px;
}
#tablebaseright{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 300px;
}
```